# Create phone link on mobile - responsive site

Tags: android, iphone, html, mobile

How can I add in HTML5 When clicking on phone number that the mobile call directly to that number.

Somethings like this:

```
<a href="tel:213213213">21321321</a>
```

Cross mobiles and cross region.

Comment: <a href="tel:213213213">21321321</a>  works fine.

Comment: Now when click on this link in desktop app, I got an error message that need skype installed, for resolve this I should change the cursor icon on desktop (to default instead of hand) or there is better solution for responsive phone link